# How to make button interaction work in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (msg) => {
    class btn{
        constructor(id,label,style){
            this.btn = new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId(id).setLabel(label).setStyle(style)
        }
    }
    if(cmd == "test"){
        var btns = []
        for(var i = 0;i < 25;i++){
            btns.push(new btn("test" + String(i),String(i).padStart(2,"0"),ButtonStyle.Secondary))
        }
        const rows = []
        for(var i = 0;i < 25;i += 5){
            const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            for(var j = i;j < i+5 && j < 25;j++){
                row.addComponents(btns[j].btn)
            }
            rows.push(row)
        }
        testMsg = msg.reply({content:"test",components: rows})
    }
    if(msg.isButton()){
        //edit
    }
})
```

If you type "/test" you will get 25 buttons. How do I change the color of a button to green when I press each button?

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (msg) => {
    class btn{
        constructor(id,label,style){
            this.btn = new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId(id).setLabel(label).setStyle(style)
        }
    }
    if(cmd == "test"){
        var btns = []
        for(var i = 0;i < 25;i++){
            btns.push(new btn("test" + String(i),String(i).padStart(2,"0"),ButtonStyle.Secondary))
        }
        const rows = []
        for(var i = 0;i < 25;i += 5){
            const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            for(var j = i;j < i+5 && j < 25;j++){
                row.addComponents(btns[j].btn)
            }
            rows.push(row)
        }
        testMsg = msg.reply({content:"test",components: rows})
    }
    if(msg.isButton() && msg.customId == "test0"){
        testMsg.edit("test")
    }
})
```

This is my code. I wrote it as a test, but an error saying "testMsg.edit is not a function" appeared.

Comment: My solution will be: listen to the interaction when the button is pressed, and edit the message. I'll suggest you to use [Interaction Collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#interaction-collectors)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, "edit" is not a function and you cannot try to use a variable to store your integration to use a function later. You should use the msg which is your interaction.

You should use,

```
await msg.reply({content:"test",components: rows})
```

and then:

```
msg.editReply('test2')
```

Explanation: You have to wait for the message to be replied and then you can edit your reply.
https://discordjs.guide/interactions/modals.html#interaction-collectors